# how to pass params via link_to in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, link-to

I have two questionaires.rb like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Questionaire do
menu :label => proc{ I18n.t("menu.admin.questionaire") }, :priority => 25
# actions :all, :except => [:create, :destroy]
filter :role
filter :name
config.comments = false
scope :all

def new
    create!
end

index do 
    column :id
    column :name
    column :role
    column :description
    column do |ques|
       link_to t("activeadmin.questionaire.add_question"), new_admin_question_path
    end
    column do |ques|
        link_to t("activeadmin.questionaire.show_question"), admin_questions_path
    end
    default_actions

end

form do |f|
  f.inputs :questionaire do
    f.input :id, :as => :hidden
    f.input :name
    f.input :role
    f.input :description

  end
f.actions
end
```

end

and one questionaire has_many questions, and questions belong_to questionaire.

and in the questions table,I add this:

```
t.references :questionaire
add_index :questions, :questionaire_id
```

But when I click the link:

```
link_to t("activeadmin.questionaire.add_question"), new_admin_question_path
```

the questionaire_id is blank!
How can I get the questionaire_id, and when click each link of each questionaire to add questions, these questions just belong to their questionaire?

edit: 
the results of questions and questionaires after rake routes:

```
batch_action_admin_questionaires POST   /admin/questionaires/batch_action(.:format)                         admin/questionaires#batch_action
                        admin_questionaires GET    /admin/questionaires(.:format)                                      admin/questionaires#index
                                            POST   /admin/questionaires(.:format)                                      admin/questionaires#create
                     new_admin_questionaire GET    /admin/questionaires/new(.:format)                                  admin/questionaires#new
                    edit_admin_questionaire GET    /admin/questionaires/:id/edit(.:format)                             admin/questionaires#edit
                         admin_questionaire GET    /admin/questionaires/:id(.:format)                                  admin/questionaires#show
                                            PUT    /admin/questionaires/:id(.:format)                                  admin/questionaires#update
                                            DELETE /admin/questionaires/:id(.:format)                                  admin/questionaires#destroy
               batch_action_admin_questions POST   /admin/questions/batch_action(.:format)                             admin/questions#batch_action
                            admin_questions GET    /admin/questions(.:format)                                          admin/questions#index
                                            POST   /admin/questions(.:format)                                          admin/questions#create
                         new_admin_question GET    /admin/questions/new(.:format)                                      admin/questions#new
                        edit_admin_question GET    /admin/questions/:id/edit(.:format)                                 admin/questions#edit
                             admin_question GET    /admin/questions/:id(.:format)                                      admin/questions#show
                                            PUT    /admin/questions/:id(.:format)                                      admin/questions#update
                                            DELETE /admin/questions/:id(.:format)                                      admin/questions#destroy
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `rake routes` ?

Comment: I already added the rake routes result, thx~

Comment: Please see this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795234/pass-a-parameter-to-the-new-action-in-active-admin

Comment: @dipakjadam  I tried this but went wrong, so I think it's not work. it turned out to be something else. Fixed it already~ thx~